# Error with Data source in APEX Office Print

Tags: sql, report, oracle-apex

This is my Data source for running APEX Office Print:

```
select 
  'file1' as "filename",  
  cursor(select  
           R.BILL_ID as "broj_racuna", 
           R.DATE as "datum_izdavanja",  
           K.CUSTOMER_NAME as "ime",
           K.CUSTOMER_ID as "oib_kupca", 
           M.CITY_NAME as "naziv_mjesta", 
           N.PAYMENT_METHOD_NAME as "naziv_nacina_placanja", 
         cursor(select 
            S.ITEM_NUMBER as "rbr", 
            S.TRANSPORT_ITEM_ID as "sifra_usluge" , 
            P.TRANSPORT_NAME as "naziv_usluge" 
            from BILL_ITEM S, TRANSPORT P 
            where P.TRANSPORT_ID=S.TRANSPORT_ITEM_ID
            and S.ITEM_BILL_ID=:P25_BILL_NUMBER
            order by S.ITEM_NUMBER) as "racun" 
           from BILL R, CUSTOMER K, CITY M, PAYMENT_METHOD N 
           where R.CUSTOMER_ID_BILL=K.CUSTOMER_ID
           and K.ZIP_CODE_CUSTOMER=M.ZIP_CODE
           and R.PAYMENT_METHOD_ID_BILL=N.PAYMENT_METHOD_ID
           and R.BILL_ID=:P25_BILL_NUMBER
        ) as "data" 
from dual
```

It says that Validation is successful but on my report are shown all attributes, but this part is missing:

```
cursor(select 
            S.ITEM_NUMBER as "rbr", 
            S.TRANSPORT_ITEM_ID as "sifra_usluge" , 
            P.TRANSPORT_NAME as "naziv_usluge" 
            from BILL_ITEM S, TRANSPORT P 
            where P.TRANSPORT_ID=S.TRANSPORT_ITEM_ID
            and S.ITEM_BILL_ID=:P25_BILL_NUMBER
            order by S.ITEM_NUMBER) as "racun"
```

Does anyone know what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure you specify P25_BILL_NUMBER in Affected Elements?

My guess is AOP sees that page item as being null, by specifying the item in Affected Elements, it will put the item's value in session state.

Hope that helps,
Dimitri

Comment: It doesn't help :(

Comment: Sorry to hear it doesn't help.

Can you try your query in SQL Developer or other tool and see if you have data there?

Comment: It doesn't executes (this middle part). Am I missing some join or something?

Comment: if you run this: select 
            S.ITEM_NUMBER as "rbr", 
            S.TRANSPORT_ITEM_ID as "sifra_usluge" , 
            P.TRANSPORT_NAME as "naziv_usluge" 
            from BILL_ITEM S, TRANSPORT P 
            where P.TRANSPORT_ID=S.TRANSPORT_ITEM_ID
            and S.ITEM_BILL_ID=:P25_BILL_NUMBER
            order by S.ITEM_NUMBER;
 
 what do you get? just focus on getting a result with that query.
 it's hard to tell you what you miss without data and table definition.

Comment: I have found the error, it was not in the SQL query. But thank you.